# Ayuda con Gridview Expand Collapse

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Que tal tengo un griview en ASP .NET con c# el cual trae una info de una BD DE SQL Server, lo que intento hacer es algo así [algo asi](http://0%20%20%20Que%20tal%20tengo%20un%20griview%20en%20ASP%20.NET%20con%20c#%20el%20cual%20trae%20una%20info%20de%20una%20BD%20DE%20SQL%20Server,%20lo%20que%20intento%20hacer%20es%20algo%20as%C3%AD%20ver%20enlace,%20me%20gui%C3%A9%20en%20esta%20pagina,%20pero%20al%20dar%20clic%20en%20la%20imagen%20%22mas%22%20me%20muestra%20el%20segundo%20gridview%20r%C3%A1pido%20y%20desaparece%20ademas%20que%20no%20me%20deja%20abrir%20las%20dem%C3%A1s%20filas,%20solo%20una%20hasta%20que%20vuelva%20a%20recargar%20la%20pagina,%20nose%20si%20me%20estoy%20explicando%20bien), me guié en esta [pagina](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-with-Expand-Collapse-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx), pero al dar clic en la imagen "mas" me muestra el segundo gridview rápido y desaparece ademas que no me deja abrir las demás filas, solo una hasta que vuelva a recargar la pagina, nose si me estoy explicando bien.
Aquí dejo mi código con el que me base en los links ya mencionados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UDP" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="Codigo1,Codigo2">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<img alt="" style="cursor: pointer; width:10%; height:6%; margin:0;padding:0;" src="../../Image/icon_plus.png" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDatos" runat="server" Style="display: none">

<asp:GridView ID="Gridview3" runat="server" autoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Sector" HeaderText="Sector" SortExpression="Sector" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Pronostico" SortExpression="" DataFormatString="{0:N0}" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Entrega" SortExpression="Entregado" DataFormatString="{0:N0}" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Total" sortExpression="Total" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

</asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo1" HeaderText="Codigo1" SortExpression="Codigo1" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="Nombre" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo2" HeaderText="Codigo2" SortExpression="Codigo2" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="Descripcion" />                            
<asp:BoundField DataField="Hectareas" HeaderText="Ha" sortExpression="Hectareas" DataFormatString="{0:N1}" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").on("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../../Image/icon_minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").on("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "../../Image/icon_plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Con el metodo RowDataBound lleno el gridview que quiero mostrar con los datakeynames del gridview1

```html
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
try
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
codigo1 = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();
codigo2 = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Values[1].ToString(); 
GridView Gridview3 = e.Row.FindControl("Gridview3") as GridView;   string query = "select * from tabla..etc where codigo1 = '" + codigo1 +"' and codigo2 = "+codigo2+"";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);                    
Gridview3.DataSource=dt;
Gridview3.DataBind();                   
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
ex.ToString();
}
}
```

Gracias.